Writing interdependent if else statements?
Is there any advantage to one of these over the other? Also, is there any better code than these to achieve the goal? My intuition is that in number 2, since it has already checked for x or y, the check for y is more efficient?


if x or y:
    do some stuff
if y:
    do some OTHER stuff



if x or y:
    do some stuff
    if y:
        do some OTHER stuff




If y is expensive to check then you might avoid checking it twice in case 2. But in most cases you should do whatever makes your code easier to follow.

i don't see why 2 would be more efficient without storing the result. 1 would be easier to read with elif

Depends on what is more expensive. If x is expensive then you might want if y: do some stuff and some other stuff elif x: do some stuff as it can avoid calculating x if y is true.

The second one is marginally more efficient, because it won't redundantly test for y again in the case where x and y are both False. In cases where x and y are often False (i.e. the first if is rarely entered), this results in a slight improvement in performance.
However, it should be noted that this improvement is very slight, and there is a tradeoff to making this change: the code becomes less readable due to the extra nesting level of if y.
If y is expensive to compute, it will be better to pre-compute (cache) the condition once rather than evaluating it twice. That will improve performance much more than micro-optimizing the arrangement of these if statements.

Agreed, except that I find 2 more readable. There is some customization with x or y and then more if y. I think this one is the the eye of the beholder.

Yeah, and I think it probably also depends on the code itself and how the stuff bits are related to each other (if they are).

I would say to use:
if y:
    do some stuff
    do some OTHER stuff
elif x:
    do some stuff

no way you are losing something here in this code, make do some stuff as function so you dont have to write it twice,
This gains cpu advantage against both your codes(calculates y once),
And memory advantage if you were planning to store y.
Also your'e not evaluating x if y passes.
